# Google analytics track site without tracking code

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

we did a relaunch of a website. The old site included an Google Analytics code and got tracked. The new site (on same domain) doesnt had an tracking code but got tracked why ?

Comment: Are you sure these are legitimate pageviews ? You might be receiving referral spam that's being sent to  the account.

Comment: what did u mean with legitimate pageviews ?

Comment: Anybody can send data to your accounts (provided he knows or guesses your account id) and this is often used to fill accounts with bogus data (google for "referral spam").   That way you may receive hits to your account without having code implemented.

Answer (score 1):

how long after the launch was the site tracked for? Is it still being tracked? Many users of the site may have cached JS which could still be calling googles tracking script.

Comment: For about one week the new site was not tracked but now the site is tracked again, i dont now how long the old site got tracked. You can be right with the cached JS ... mhmmm

Comment: another possibility is that the old site could be accessible via a url that you may have overlooked or forgotten about. maybe a pre-propogation url.

A useful tool for checking this is a plagiarism checker:

https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=find%20duplicate%20websites

Comment: Or check the hostname report - useful if somebody ripped you html and forgot to remove the GA code.